# how do i display long text after click read more button with shorted text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm using an accordion panel for long comments in my blog. Now I want to add long text to short text and show the full text with this, but I have a problem. If I click the show button, it shows at a newline.

[jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/h2sb7kth/1/)

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default text-left" >
    <div>
      <div style="color:#000;" class="panel-body text-left"><br>This is short comment for my stack...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" >
    <div id="collapse2" class="clearfix panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body" style="color:#000;">overflow post and i hope i can find a good solution for this
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">'.
        <h5><a class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Show/Hide</a>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add another part to short text ***without newline***.

Comment: `div` elements are block elements by default, meaning their contents will start on a new line. You'll either need to adjust your markup so that the rest of the text resides in the same block element, or add styles to force all non-shared ancestral `div` elements of both the short text and full text to have a display property of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second part of your text in a span and hide it, then reveal it with JS:

```js
function showMore()
{
    if ($('#threedots').css('display')=='none')
    {
        //already showing, we hide
            $('#threedots').show();
            $('#full_desc').hide();
    }
    else
    {
            //show more
            $('#threedots').hide();
            $('#full_desc').show();

    }


}//end function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color:#000;" class="panel-body text-left"><br>This is short comment for my stack<span id="threedots">...</span><span id="full_desc" style="display:none">overflow post and i hope i can find a good solution for this</span></div>
  <a class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onclick="showMore()">Show/Hide</a>
```